mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/ntfs’: Input/output error
I have an ntfs disk and am trying to mount it.
I have installed the ntfs-3g and while trying to mkdir ntfs in /mnt
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/ntfs
I get the error
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/ntfs’: Input/output error
How do I resolve this error?

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

What is /mnt? Have you mounted your NTFS disk there? If not, where is it mounted? How did you mount it? With what command? Can you show us the output of mount | grep -i ntfs? And Linux has had native NTFS support for years, there's no need to install ntfs-3g.

You didn't provide clues as to your OS/release, nor the actual command you used to perform mount (ie. you may not have mounted it RW), OR if you mounted a file-system and issues were detected (ie. unclean state detected due to fastboot/hibernate active) it would be mounted RO or read only meaning you cannot make changes. Refer back to your mount for clues; and if you used a GUI tool you may need to review system logs for messages.   (FYI:  This is pretty much same detail as prior commentators worded differently; ie. review your approach)
